# Utilização da função soundex mysql com parametro like

Tags: mysql, soundex

Como posso utilizar da função soundex do mysql como parametro like

por exemplo tenho uma tabela pessoas
com o nome Poliana Mendes Silva

quero procurar com o soundex todas as "polianas" do banco
ignorando o resto do nome

Comment: O soundex gera uma string única para várias palavras, não é pra ser usado com funções de substring como Like. Para este tipo de coisa, melhor fulltext. Além disso, soundex é "tunado" para a língua inglesa.

Comment: PS: Até daria pra você fazer algo do tipo, mas teria que fazer um campo especial de nomes gravados com soundex palavra a palavra, e criar uma função para preencher esse campo sempre que os dados forem inseridos ou modificados. Provavelmente, fazer tudo isso e gastar espaço a mais para um sistema que foi projetado para a lingua inglesa não vai ficar melhor do que fulltext de qualquer forma.

Comment: Consegui resolver assim
"SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE "
                                . "SOUNDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME_COMPLETO, ' ', 1) ) = SOUNDEX('PAULA') "
                                . "AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME_COMPLETO, ' ', -1) = :SOBRENOME"

Comment: A lógica é mais ou menos essa, mas como vc deve ter percebido, vai ser sofrido você gerenciar nomes como "João Augusto Conrado do Amaral Gurgel". Como experiência vale, mas como solução pra um sistema real, vai te dar mais trabalho do que solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver assim

"SELECT * FROM Clientes WHERE SOUNDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME_COMPLETO, ' ', 1) ) = SOUNDEX('PAULA') AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(NOME_COMPLETO, ' ', -1) = 'SOBRENOME'"